# How to convert an improper fraction with variables to a mixed number?

Tags: fractions

I have fractions like these: $$\frac{12000x}{41}\qquad (1)\\\frac{12000+x}{41}\qquad (2)\\$$
What is the process to convert these to a mixed number (example: $5\frac12$)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Note $41$ is prime.  You do this in the usual way, dividing the numerator by the denominator to get a quotient and remainder.

Comment: There is not enough information in question to understand, what author is looking for. $\frac{f(x)}{41}=\lfloor \frac{f(x)}{41}\rfloor + \left(\frac{f(x)}{41}-\lfloor \frac{f(x)}{41}\rfloor\right)$. $\frac{12000x}{41}=\frac{12000}{41}x=292\frac{28}{41}\; x$. $\frac{12000+x}{41}=292\frac{28}{41}+\frac{x}{41}$. If $x$ is integer and $0\leq x<13$ then $\frac{12000+x}{41}=292\frac{28+x}{41}$

Comment: For $r \in \Bbb{R},~$ let $\lfloor r\rfloor$ (i.e. the floor function) denote the largest integer $\leq r$.  Then, $$\left\lfloor \frac{12000}{41}\right\rfloor = 292 \implies \frac{12000}{41} = 292 + \frac{28}{41}.$$  Therefore, $$\frac{12000x}{41} = 292x + \frac{28x}{41},$$ while $$\frac{12000 + x}{41} = 292 + \frac{28}{41} + \frac{x}{41}.$$

Comment: Re my previous comment, and as (also) indicated by the comment of @IvanKaznacheyeu, since $x$ is (presumably) a variable with no fixed value, you can not be more precise than the expressions in my previous comment.